# Solve $x^9+x^6 = 36$ without making a guess at any step

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Okay, my friend asked me to solve this equation:
$$x^9+x^6 = 36$$
I did this by substituting $a = x^3$:
$$a^3+a^2 = 36$$
$$a^2(a+1) = 36\tag{1}\label{1}$$
Here, I saw that $a = 3$ is a solution. I told my friend that the answer was $x = \sqrt[3]3$, and showed them how I solved it. But, they asked me to solve it without making a guess at the step $\eqref{1}$. How should I go about this? Also, how to show that this is the only solution in $\Bbb R$? (Verified by graphing it)

---

Edit: I forgot to add that please don't use things like the cubic formula (haven't really managed to wrap my head around it).

Comment: Note there are two other complex solutions to (1).  I don't see any issue with guess-and-check or using the rational root theorem, but if you want, you could use the general solution to the cubic [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula).

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I don't think they expected me to use Cubic formula

Comment: I don't understand this question. What counts as "making a guess" exactly? The rational root theorem gives a finite list of candidates for rational solutions to the equation, and by checking them all we find $a=3$ is a solution.

Comment: @DavidLui but it still involves guessing by trial and error, doesn't it

Comment: Applying the Rational Roots test is *not* guesswork. It can be tedious, but common sense estimates often eliminate many of the possibilities without much effort.

Comment: @TedShifrin yeah but how are you sure that there aren't any irrational solutions to (1)

Comment: Of course there will be. How will you find those without reducing to an application of the quadratic or cubic formulas?

Comment: @TedShifrin see the accepted answer below, and my comment on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a \le 0$. If $a < -1$ then $a^2(a+ 1) < 0$ so we must also have $a \ge -1$. Now on $[-1, 0]$, $a^2 \le 1$ and $a + 1 \le 1$, so $a^2(a + 1) \le 1$. In particular there is no solution with $a \le 0$.

If $a \ge 0$ then $a + 1 \ge 1$, so $a^2 \le 36$ and hence $a \le 6$. On $[0, 6]$, both $a^2$ and $a + 1$ are increasing, so $a^2(a + 1)$ increases from $0$ to $72$. Therefore there is at most one solution (exactly one if you know about continuity), which a priori you could find to arbitrary accuracy by bisection: check the midpoint of the candidate interval, if the value is $=36$ then you've found a solution, if the value is $<36$ then the solution is to the right, if its $> 36$ then the solution is to the left. In this case the procedure terminates at the very first check.

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that if we change the $36$ to eg $12$, the unique solution for $a$ is the integer $2$ but following the procedure outlined will only produce approximations since you start with the interval $[0, \sqrt{3}]$ and bisecting this in whatever ways can only produce rational multiples of $\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

Write: $a^3 - 27 + a^2 - 9 = 0 \implies (a-3)(a^2+3a +9) + (a-3)(a+3) = 0$. Do you see a common factor ?

Comment: so we get $(a-3)(a^2+4a+12)$, which gives one solution $a= 3$. But $a^2+4a+12 = 0$ has no solutions since $4^2 - 4\cdot1\cdot12$ is negative. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: thanks, the problem had been bugging me for hours. Also, how did you see that the equation could be factorised?

Comment: Since $3$ is a solution, so $x-3$ is a factor by the factor theorem. So you know somehow you can factor it with few steps at most.

Comment: yeah, but aren't we using the $a=3$ guess here? Anyways, it's an excellent answer

Comment: @DS FYI, once you know 3 is solution, you can immediately factor it by polynomial division

Comment: @Golden_Ratio "once you know". But anyways, we can make a guess, factor it, and tell our friends we didn't guess it, but solved it by factoring. So I'll accept this answer

Comment: @DS Right, once you know.  Again, I don't see any problem with using the rational root theorem to search for rational solutions; this is an algorithmic approach to at least eliminate solutions. It sounds like you want a general formulaic approach, but don't want to use the cubic formula. In any case, once you get beyond degree 4, the problem of factoring has [no general solution in radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange resolvents are not wellcome by OP. I understand that. I tried another trick.

Let $a=\frac {3}{y}$ then $4y^3-y-3=0$. Now, let $y=\cos\theta$ (Here there may be some objections.) Then, $4\cos^3\theta-\cos\theta-3=0$ and by $\cos3\theta=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta$ triple angle formula we get
$$\cos3\theta=3-2\cos\theta.$$
Hence, $\cos\theta=y=1$ and $a=3.$